# How to clear certain images from cache Glide

Tags: android, caching, android-glide, image-caching, clear-cache

I am gonna make image cache strategy like: i have 2 url for 1 image, first 34×34 px i use as a thumb and second main 300×300px. I need to cache both, but second type (300×300) i want to clear once a week with work manager. How to make it with Glide.

```
Because glide clear all cache with Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.